# Window onload displays saved innerHTML but dosen't read classnames of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage

I have this program that makes draggable "text" that can be dropped into a td in a table. I save the innerHTML of the table in local storage. The user can view the table they created in another page and edit the table there. I've run in to a couple of problems with the ways the user can edit the table on the edit page.

One of the problems I'm running into: When the user loads the page, the innerHTML of the saved table is shown to the user who can then press delete buttons located on the right of the table.  But right now when you click the delete buttons it's as if the program isn't reading the innerHTML of the table even though I set the table before any of the other function, I'm not sure why it isn't reading the class names of the delete buttons

**I get and set the table with this function:**

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    getAndSet();
});

function getAndSet(){
  var table = localStorage.getItem('Table');
  console.log(table);
  document.getElementById("tableInIndex").innerHTML = table;
} 
//----------more code--------------IN THIS ORDER
```

The table has the id="tbUser" and when one it's delete buttons is clicked the closes tr to the delete button is deleted, right now the classnames in the table aren't being read an I'm unsure why:

```
$("#tbUser").on('click', '.btnDelete', function () { //PROBLEM: there are delete button in each row of the table and I detect which ones clicked with there class name but it's not reading there classnames and I'm unsure why
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Here is an example of a table:

```
<table border="1" style="border-color: grey;" id="tbUser">
<tbody><tr>
<th width="100">Time</th>
    <th width="100">Monday</th>
    <th width="100">Tuesday</th>
    <th width="100">Wednesday</th>
    <th width="100">Thursday</th>
    <th width="100">Friday</th>
  </tr>
    
  <tr>
    <th class="th" width="100">1:00 PM</th>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td class="delTr ui-droppable"><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="th" width="100">2:00 PM</th>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td class="delTr ui-droppable"><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="th" width="100">3:00 PM</th>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td class="delTr ui-droppable"><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="th" width="100">4:00 PM</th>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td class="delTr ui-droppable"><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="th" width="100">5:00 PM</th>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td class="delTr ui-droppable"><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="th" width="100">6:00 PM</th>
    <td width="100" class=""><div class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative;">text</div></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td>
    <td class="delTr ui-droppable"><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
<tr><th class="th" width="100">7:00 PM</th><td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td><td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td><td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td><td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td><td width="100" class="ui-droppable"></td><td class="delTr ui-droppable"><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I'm planning on inserting a plunker of my code if it's too vague of a question to come to a solution, but I wanted to see if it was feasible to detect whats causing the problem solely on this information.

**Edit**: Here is the plunker of my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/xEse0Pnri20vFpl0?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` <-- You say that this is your way of finding an element based on a class name, but that's not what it's doing. It's looking for the nearest ancestor `<tr>` element, not class name and, as far as I can tell from your plunker, it's working correctly.

Comment: Also, there is no code (that you've shown) that checks `localStorage` to see if there is a table already stored there - - you just go and set your table up with the `localStorage` value, even if there isn't any.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I meant this is my way of finding an element based on it's classname: the table is saved with the id="tbUser" I use this to find the delete buttons based on there classname: `$("#tbUser").on('click', '.btnDelete', function ()...` will that do the trick?

Comment: Hi, try like this `$(document).on('click', '.btnDelete', function (){ //your codes })`